# Beginner trouble understanding composer and frameworks

Tags: php, composer-php

im having a really big problem understanding the usage of composer and frameworks.

The tutorials i have seen use some kind of online-editor so they dont really help me.
I learned about OOP etc and now i want to do the next step and learn about frameworks and composer.

I have a server and already managed to install composer. Plus i managed to install packages.

But what now? Can you tell me at a very basic level how to make use of this stuff?

I have an editor on my notebook and installed composer on my server. How do I interact with the classes?

Do i just write them and upload the file to check if it works? Do i somehow install them on my local environment? And if yes, how would i deploy my project afterwards?

I know its much but im not getting the basics of usage here :(

Thank you very much!

I watched tutorial for hours now but they always just seem to use the stuff. And i dont know how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have to understand is that Composer is only a package manager, it will allow you to download some libraries (and their dependencies), and provide you an autoloader file to include on your files, so that you can use library classes.

Actually, you better install Composer on your local machine, develop your website locally, then, when it's ready, deploy it to your server.

A simple example, supposing you want to use [Silex](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/) microframework.

**Install Silex with composer**

```
composer require 'silex/silex:1.3.0'
```

**Include Silex in your script**

Including Composer autoloader file

```
<?php
require_once './vendor/autoload.php';

$app = new Silex\Application(); 
?>
```

**Develop**

It's up to you, test it locally with a webserver installed on your computer.

**Deploy**

Deploy your website by pushing it on your webserver (with a FTP client for example).

Comment: Thank your for your answer, actually helps me a lot. I will first use it on my computer now to learn more and not bother with the other stuff for now. Learning this stuff sometimes can get frustrating. Thank you for helping me out!